# Page postback even though validate function returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0, JS, and Jquery for some validation. My js is throwing this error after my validation runs and returns false. It also is allowing for a post back to occur.

JS excerpt throwing the error:

```
 var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        Sys.Observer.raiseEvent(this, "endRequest", eventArgs);
        if (error && !eventArgs.get_errorHandled()) {
            throw error;
        }
```

My full error message:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
ScriptResource.axd, line 938 character 13
```

my JS:

```
  if (regex) {
                result = patt.test($(this).val());
            } if (!result) {
                //return false;
                $(this).focus();
                alert("Please enter the " + failed_type + " in the following format: " + format);
                return false;
            }
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" 
        Text="Update" CssClass="button" 
        TabIndex="4" OnClientClick="return update_Click(event);" OnClick="Update_Click" />
```

Call Stack:

```
PageRequestManager$_endPostback,ScriptResource.axd line 938
PageRequestManager$_parseDelta,ScriptResource.axd line 1653
PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted,ScriptResource.axd line 1414
Anonymous Function, ScriptResource.axd, line627
Anonymous function, ScriptResource.axd, line 4337
raise, ScriptResource.axd, line 7247 
WebRequest$completed, ScriptResource.axd, line 7251
WebRequest$completed, ScriptResource.axd, line 7251
```

Comment: If you look at the call stack what's the last bit of your code that was running before the exception?

Comment: See Page edit, added the stack

Comment: I believe this error is coming from the postback still occuring even though I have returned false.  Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think the validation is causing your issues. To test see what happens if you remove the OnClientClick event on your update button

Comment: Same error, I use js to massage the data and store which elements to write to the DB, so this is throwing an error saying there is nothing to write.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what's on the page though in order for it to be POSTed back to the server. With the OnClientClick removed your server event Update_Click still doesn't get hit?

Comment: It is getting hit, the error actually comes after the Update_Click function throws a System.IndexOutOfRangeException because I save to a hidden control in my OnClientClick function

Comment: Cool, can you post up the whole ClientClick method?